# Warning messages from scapy

Tags: python, warnings, scapy

Using this:

```
from scapy.all import *
```

I've got these two warnings which I want to remove

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
> "C:\Users\localfp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scapy\layers\ipsec.py",
> line 471
> cipher=algorithms.Blowfish, CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
>
> Warning (from warnings module):   File
> "C:\Users\localfp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scapy\layers\ipsec.py",
> line 485
> cipher=algorithms.CAST5, CryptographyDeprecationWarning: CAST5 has been deprecated

Unfortunately I've found the solution for this kind of error only for paramiko.

I'm using this in order to sniff packets from an ethernet II connection.
Is there a way to remove these two warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general solution (if you only want to ignore the CryptographyDeprecationWarning) but keep the rest of the warnings:

```
import warnings
from cryptography.utils import CryptographyDeprecationWarning
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=CryptographyDeprecationWarning)

from scapy.all import *
```

Answer (score 3):

It worked using code like this (I'm using python 3):

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently fixed in https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/3645 and will be included in Scapy 2.5.0+ (use the github version in the meantime)